# Runtime exception "Unable to determine the appropriate ebean platform given database product name" using ebean 13.25.2-jakarta

Tags: java, jpa, ebean

I have a project using ebean 13.25.2-jakarta. I've included

```
io.ebean.ebean
io.ebean.ebean-ddl-generator
```

I'm configuring ebean programmatically

```
dataSourceConfig.setUsername(configService.get(DB_USERNAME));
dataSourceConfig.setPassword(configService.get(DB_PASSWORD));
dataSourceConfig.setUrl(configService.get(DB_URL));
dataSourceConfig.setDriver(configService.get(DB_DRIVER));
dataSourceConfig.setPlatform(configService.get(DB_PLATFORM));
/*
* configuration
*/
databaseConfig.setDdlGenerate(configService.getAsBoolean(DB_DDL_GENERATE));
databaseConfig.setDdlRun(configService.getAsBoolean(DB_DDL_GENERATE));
// databaseConfig.setDdlCreateOnly(false);
databaseConfig.setDataSourceConfig(dataSourceConfig);
/*
* create database instance
*/
database = DatabaseFactory.create(databaseConfig);
```

Unit testing with setPlatform('h2') works, however PROD configuration with setPlatform('mysql') doesn't.

This error is produced:

`Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to determine the appropriate ebean platform given database product name [mysql] and ebean platform providers [H2]. With ebean 13+ we now have separate platforms (ebean-postgres, ebean-mysql etc) and should use database specific platform dependency like ebean-postgres. Note that we can use ebean-platform-all to include all the platforms.`

I'm not sure what to do from here. I've tried include ebean-platform-all and the result is the same.

Edit: added information

```
The DB settings when running unit tests are:

Username: sa
Password: sa
URL: jdbc:h2:file:~/ipdb.db
Driver: org.h2.Driver
Platform: h2
DDL Generate: true
DDL Run: true
```

The unit tests run and pass.   The PROD settings, which fail are:

```
Username: ipdb
Password: 123qwe
URL: jdbc:mysql://db/ipdb
Driver: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
Platform: mysql
DDL Generate: true
DDL Run: false
```

The full stack trace is:

> Configuration file: ipdb.properties Username: ipdb Password: 123qwe
> URL: jdbc:mysql://db/ipdb Driver: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver Platform:
> mysql DDL Generate: true DDL Run: false
> com.khubla.ipdb.db.service.ServiceException:
> com.khubla.ipdb.db.service.ServiceException:
> com.khubla.ipdb.db.DAOException: Exception in deleteAll   at
> com.khubla.ipdb.db.service.impl.DatabaseAdminServiceImpl.createDB(DatabaseAdminServiceImpl.java:60)
> at com.khubla.ipdb.cli.Main.main(Main.java:101) Caused by:
> com.khubla.ipdb.db.service.ServiceException:
> com.khubla.ipdb.db.DAOException: Exception in deleteAll   at
> com.khubla.ipdb.db.service.impl.DatabaseAdminServiceImpl.clean(DatabaseAdminServiceImpl.java:50)
> at
> com.khubla.ipdb.db.service.impl.DatabaseAdminServiceImpl.createDB(DatabaseAdminServiceImpl.java:57)
> ... 1 more Caused by: com.khubla.ipdb.db.DAOException: Exception in
> deleteAll     at
> com.khubla.ipdb.db.GenericRelationalDAO.deleteAll(GenericRelationalDAO.java:80)
> at
> com.khubla.ipdb.db.service.impl.DatabaseAdminServiceImpl.clean(DatabaseAdminServiceImpl.java:41)
> ... 2 more Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException:
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to determine the appropriate
> ebean platform given database product name [mysql] and ebean platform
> providers [H2]. With ebean 13+ we now have separate platforms
> (ebean-postgres, ebean-mysql etc) and should use database specific
> platform dependency like ebean-postgres. Note that we can use
> ebean-platform-all to include all the platforms.  at
> io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DatabasePlatformFactory.create(DatabasePlatformFactory.java:58)
> at
> io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.setDatabasePlatform(DefaultContainer.java:219)
> at
> io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.createServer(DefaultContainer.java:109)
> at
> io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.createServer(DefaultContainer.java:33)
> at io.ebean.DatabaseFactory.createInternal(DatabaseFactory.java:135)
> at io.ebean.DatabaseFactory.create(DatabaseFactory.java:84)     at
> com.khubla.ipdb.db.DBUtil.(DBUtil.java:74)  at
> com.khubla.ipdb.db.DBUtil.getInstance(DBUtil.java:107)    at
> com.khubla.ipdb.db.GenericRelationalDAO.deleteAll(GenericRelationalDAO.java:77)
> ... 3 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to
> determine the appropriate ebean platform given database product name
> [mysql] and ebean platform providers [H2]. With ebean 13+ we now have
> separate platforms (ebean-postgres, ebean-mysql etc) and should use
> database specific platform dependency like ebean-postgres. Note that
> we can use ebean-platform-all to include all the platforms.   at
> io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DatabasePlatformFactory.byDatabaseMeta(DatabasePlatformFactory.java:104)
> at
> io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DatabasePlatformFactory.byDataSource(DatabasePlatformFactory.java:80)
> at
> io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DatabasePlatformFactory.create(DatabasePlatformFactory.java:55)
> ... 11 more

Comment: we wont be able to help you if you dont give all the info: whats DB_URL, DB_DRIVER, etc.?...also, stack trace please (are we supposed to know where that breaks?...come on!)

Comment: @PerdiEstaquel sorry about that, added more information.  Thanks for your comment.

Comment: so you setPlatform("mysql") and it comes back saying "...ebean platform providers [H2]"...i would try setPlatform("whateverInvalidPlatformString") and see what happens...also double check valid platform names...also try ebean-mysql, not ebean-platform-all...in summary: theres a value in error messages, so try different things and see how error messages change to get some clues

Comment: Well, interestingly, changing the platform name to 'Platform: invalid-name' gives this same error message: 'Unable to determine the appropriate ebean platform given database product name [mysql] and ebean platform providers [H2]'.  Thanks!

Comment: I can confirm that if I switch back to version 12.16.2 (and change to the javax dependencies from jakarta) that everything works nicely.